# Using RadioGroup and RadioButtons

Tags: java, android

Hey, I want to make the Text of a RadioButton appear on the left side of the RadioButton.. so I tried using 2 relative views (I have 2 RadioButtons) and it worked but the problem is in RadioGroup not working properly.. Heres the code:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/SearchRelative" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton android:checked="true" 
        android:id="@+id/SearchRadioButtonAloneWord" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    </RadioButton>

    <TextView android:text="1" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/SearchRadioButtonAloneWord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/SearchRelative" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/SearchRadioButtonInBetweenWord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    </RadioButton>

    <TextView android:text="2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/SearchRadioButtonInBetweenWord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

They get displayed properly with the text on the left side of its `RadioButton`.. but the `RadioGroup` doesnt work!
How can I fix this?
Thanks

**Edit1**: is it possible to dynamically add `RadioButton`s to a group? thats one way of fixing my problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding using layout managers inside a `RadioGroup`: sorry, it doesn't work that way. As far as I know, if something is added to a `RadioGroup` which is not an instance of `RadioButton`, it is not managed by this `RadioGroup`. But this presents an alterntive solution to the problem: extending `RadioButton` to draw it the way you want.

As for dynamic manipulation: yes, this is possible with `RadioGroup` just like with any other `ViewGroup`. All you have to do is to add `RadioButton`s via `RadioGroup.addView()`.

Comment: "extending RadioButton to draw it the way you want." can you please explain more what you mean

Comment: You can create your own UI component and include it in your layout. Developer's guide has an article on how to do this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html. You need to read the last section, "Modifying an Existing View Type".